# Laravel - sum searched posts price

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

How can I sum price only for posts that I searched? I have a search page and search is for date, so I search posts by a date. And when I type date that I want I need to sum all posts prices that my search function find for that date. Here is my code.

This is my search in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/search', 'PagesController@search');

Route::post('/search',function(){
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $post = auth()->user()->posts()->where('ime','LIKE', '%'.$q.'%')->get();
    if(count($post) > 0)
        return view('search')->withDetails($post)->withQuery ( $q );
    else return view ('search')->withMessage('Nema rezultata Vaše pretrage. Probajte ponovo!');
});
```

And this is my search function in `PagesController`:

```
public function search(){
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('search')->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }
```

And this is my `search.blade.php` with table footer where is should sum my posts price:

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts()->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>               
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

but when I type this it sums me price for all posts, and I just need for the searched ones. Any suggestions?

Comment: where's `price` used in your code?

Comment: Sorry it's not price its 'cijena'

Comment: well in your view you can just use `$posts->sum('cijena')` right, since you pass the `'posts'` variable to it. However, this does the sum on the collection, but it's better to do it using the query builder, that is `posts()->sum('cijena')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... but when I type this it sums me price for all posts, and I just need for the searched ones

This is because you have this line in your view:

```
<th> ... {{ Auth::user()->posts()->sum('cijena') }} ... </th>
```

This is executing a different query directly to get the total sum of the `cijena`. So, regardless of if you constraint your results or not this will keep output  the same vale. This different query has any impact on the rest of the queried values.

What you could do is to calculate that value in the main query and return it to the view:

```
Route::post('/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get('q');
    $posts = auth()->user()->posts()->where('ime', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->get();

    if (count($posts) > 0)
    {
        $sum = $posts->sum('cijena'); // <---

        return view('search')->withDetails($posts)->withTotal($sum);
    }   //                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    else
    {
        return view('search')->withMessage('Your error message goes here!');
    }
});
```

So now you'll have access to an extra variable `$total` in your blade file:

```
<th> ... {{ $total) }} ... </th>
```

---

Also, there is no need to define two routes for the same operation, you could reduce all that in one simple method. Additional, you shouldn't execute queries from your front-end. Do as follows:

```
# web.php

Route::get('/search', 'PagesController@search');
```

Then in your controller:

```
# PageController.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// ...

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $posts = auth()
        ->user()
        ->posts()
        ->when($request->has('q'), function ($q) { // first check if there is a query
            return $q->where('ime', 'LIKE', '%' . request('q') . '%'); // if so, apply filter
        })
        ->get();

    if (count($posts) > 0) // checking if there is enough posts..
    {
        $sum = $posts->sum('cijena'); // if so get the sum of 'cijena'

        return view('search')->withDetails($posts)->withTotal($sum);
    }   //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    else
    {
        return view('search')->withMessage('Your error message goes here!');
    }
}
```

---

## Update

This line is the one that throws the error:

> ```
> <p class="searchp">Rezultati vaše pretrage <b> {{$q}} </b>: </p>
> ```

This is because I didn't include a `$q` variable. Just append it to your response in case you need it:

```
// ...
return view('search')->withDetails($posts)->withTotal($sum)->with('q', request('q'));
// ...
```

Comment: Okay now its working fine. But I have two problems, one is that now on search page before I put anything for search its showing me all posts created, i just need not to show anything before I search for posts, and the second one is that I have a error from my search.blade.php for ```Undefined variable: q```, let me show you the code

Comment: @Milos the error might be because you are using the variable somewhere in your view, try to find the `$q`. If you don't want to show anything at the beginning then modify the code to check first if there is a query input  (`$request->has('q')`) and then make a if/else statement to put the query in the `if` part and your default response in the `else` part.

Comment: so I just need to put ```$request->has('q')``` before if and else ?
And I also add ```with('q', request('q'));``` where you told me but nothing happens, same error again

Comment: It should work. Try `dd(request('q'))` in your controller to see if you are setting that value in your view.. if so.. make sure to put the line as I showed. You could also use another variable name like `->withTerm(request('q'));` son then in your view replace `$q` with `$term`.

Comment: Also @Milos this following questions seems to form part of a new question itself with a proper explanation in case you can't solve the issue. I hope I have been helpful.